# Books or authors who write about how to write mathematics properly

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, proof-writing, book-recommendation

I've always been interested how to write maths properly. Depending of the knowledge of the reader, you can't solve every detail of a proof of a theorem. You have to show the most important facts, unless your proof turns out tedious and languish. I'm writing a little paper about this to my students and I would like to know some authors who discuss about this, I need some references.

Comment: I only know this by reference and haven't looked at it, but maybe take a look at: Nicholas J. Higham, *Handbook of Writing for the Mathematical Sciences*, SIAM 1998.

Comment: I've seen this Halmos piece referenced before: http://www.math.washington.edu/~lind/Resources/Halmos.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Jean Pierre Serre is in some sense a reference on good article writing. I would  watch the awesome lecture of him "[How to write mathematics badly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECQyFzzBHlo)". Gives very good insights that you could pass to your students.

I would also suggest [Mathematical Writing](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dDOehHMbUMcC&lpg=PP1&dq=Mathematical%20Writing%20knuth&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=Mathematical%20Writing%20knuth&f=false), of Donald Knuth

Answer (score 2):

See these books:

- [A Primer of Mathematical Writing](http://bookstore.ams.org/pmw)
  by Steven G. Kranz.
- [Handbook of Writing for the Mathematical Sciences](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719550) by Nicholas J. Hingham.